# cmd upload (windows server 2012)

Tags: ftp, cmd

I have command in ftp.txt

```
open ftp.web.cz
jmeno
heslo
prompt
mput C:\upload\*
quit
```

This command call in ftp. bat (ftp -s:C:\ftp.txt ), but show error -  Error opening local file.Can I help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `lcd` to change local working directory and `cd` to change remote working directory. Consider whether specify `ascii` and / or `binary` transfer type.

```
open ftp.web.cz
jmeno
heslo
prompt
[cd "/destinationfolder"]
lcd "C:\upload"
mput *.*
quit
```

Comment: Thank you. After upload has file zero size.

Comment: What file type? Maybe it's in a discrepancy to transfer type (default = `ascii`).